# How to merge 2 scripts? to animate a character with boolean and code in unity scripting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, animation, boolean

I am trying to do what the title entails but I don't know code very well and i've been following tuts all day, I know the solution is *learn to code* but regardless I'm kinda stuck here, I copied the first half of the code from a unity doc site about animating and moving the character.

The second half I followed a tutorial on yt and edited to my liking.

One half is supposed to actually move the character around and the other is supposed to play animations when pressing a button, I'm using boolean to play the animations and such:

If there's another way please tell me! I won't learn anything unless someone tells me whats wrong!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimationStateController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CharacterController controller;
    private Vector3 playerVelocity;
    private bool groundedPlayer;
    private float playerSpeed = 2.0f;
    private float jumpHeight = 1.0f;
    private float gravityValue = -9.81f;

    private void Start()
    {
        controller = gameObject.AddComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        groundedPlayer = controller.isGrounded;
        if (groundedPlayer && playerVelocity.y < 0)
        {
            playerVelocity.y = 0f;
        }

        Vector3 move = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        controller.Move(move * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed);

        if (move != Vector3.zero)
        {
            gameObject.transform.forward = move;
        }

        // Changes the height position of the player..
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("idle") && groundedPlayer)
        {
            playerVelocity.y += Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -3.0f * gravityValue);
        }

        playerVelocity.y += gravityValue * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(playerVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
        Animator animator;
        int isRunningHash;
        {

        void Update()
        {
            animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
            isRunningHash = Animator.StringToHash("isRunning");
            bool isRunning = animator.GetBool("isRunning");
            bool forwardPressed = Input.GetKey("w");
            // if player presses w key
            if (!isRunning  && forwardPressed)
            {
                animator.SetBool("isRunning", true);
            }
            if (isRunning && !forwardPressed)
            {
                animator.SetBool("isRunning", false);
            }
            bool isJumping = animator.GetBool("isJumping");
            bool spacePressed = Input.GetKey("j");
            if (!isJumping  && spacePressed)
            {
                animator.SetBool("isJumping", true);
                animator.SetBool("isRunning", false);
            }
            if (isJumping && !spacePressed)
            {
                animator.SetBool("isJumping", false);
                animator.SetBool("isRunning", true);
            }
        }
```

I'm putting it in github because this site doesn't allow the "public class" part

Comment: There's no reason you shouldn't be able to edit the script into the question directly. There are many questions with "public class" in them. When you do add it be sire to try and ask a more specific question too. It isn't clear what you need. Is there an error? What is it? Is something not working? What is it supposed to do that it isn't?

Comment: Please add the hyperlinks from where you have been following the blog or looking at yt tutorial. Thanks

Comment: You have a update method inside the update method. Don’t think you wanted that

Comment: I did say I didn't know much at all about coding with c#! I also don't go on this site as much neither because they only allow "smart" questions so I didn't know weather or not what is wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Looking into your code it doesn't make much sense currently.

The weirdness begins after line

```
int isRunningHash;
```

there is a `{` and then it just doesn't make sense anymore. You have a local function `Update` nested under your method `Update`...

It should probably rather have been something like e.g.

```
public class AnimationStateController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CharacterController controller;
    private Vector3 playerVelocity;
    private bool groundedPlayer;
    private float playerSpeed = 2.0f;
    private float jumpHeight = 1.0f;
    private float gravityValue = -9.81f;

    private Animator animator;
    private int isRunningHash;
    private int isJumpingHash;
 
    private void Start()
    {
        controller = gameObject.AddComponent<CharacterController>();

        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        isRunningHash = Animator.StringToHash("isRunning");
        isJumpingHash = Animator.StringToHash("isJumping");
    }

    void Update()
    {
        groundedPlayer = controller.isGrounded;

        if (groundedPlayer && playerVelocity.y < 0)
        {
            playerVelocity.y = 0f;
        }

        var move = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        controller.Move(move * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed);

        if (move != Vector3.zero)
        {
            transform.forward = move;
        }

        // Changes the height position of the player..
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("idle") && groundedPlayer)
        {
            playerVelocity.y += Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -3.0f * gravityValue);
        }

        playerVelocity.y += gravityValue * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(playerVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
        
            
        //var isRunning = animator.GetBool("isRunning");
        //var forwardPressed = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W);
        //if (!isRunning  && forwardPressed)
        //{
        //    animator.SetBool(isRunningHash, true);
        //}
        //else if (isRunning && !forwardPressed)
        //{
        //    animator.SetBool(isRunningHash, false);
        //}
        //bool isJumping = animator.GetBool("isJumping");
        //bool spacePressed = Input.GetKey(Keycode.Space);
        //if (!isJumping  && spacePressed)
        //{
        //    animator.SetBool("isJumping", true);
        //    animator.SetBool("isRunning", false);
        //}
        //else if (isJumping && !spacePressed)
        //{
        //    animator.SetBool("isJumping", false);
        //    animator.SetBool("isRunning", true);
        //}

        // You will need to test performance wise but I think you could simply compress this to
        var forwardPressed = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W);
        var spacePressed = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space);
        animator.SetBool(isRunningHash, forwardPressed && !spacePressed);
        animator.SetBool(isJumpingHash, spacePressed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I know little to nothing about c# so I am grateful for your help, I wish there was another way, I am going to try to find some sort of thing that teaches c# because I don't ever want to feel this dumb.